# Setting given element at the given row and col position

Tags: java

I have 2D ArrayList and a method `public void set(int row, int col, T x)` that changes `this.element` to `x`. When I try running my code it gives me `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and I do not understand why because I have initialized my board:

```
Board board = new Board(-2,3,-4,3,"xxx");
```

where the constructor values are

`new Board(int minRow, int maxRow, int minCol, int maxCol, T e)`

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` happens in the `set()` method in the line:

```
if(myBoard.get(row).get(col).equals(this.element))
```

Why am I getting that error? Am I properly accessing the row and col number in ArrayList??

My `toString()` representation of the

Comment: What made you think a list accepts negative indices ?

Comment: Wait, it does not ????@Dici

Comment: Of course not, all ordered collections, and arrays, are 0-indexed (they start from 0)

Comment: make negative numbers a *rendering* issue, not a data structure issue.

Comment: @Dici, could I ask you smth? In my code `myBoard` represents `2D Arraylist` and when I do smth like `myBoard.get(row).set(col, x)` then how does it know that `myBoard` contains that element. Because I see in my code I only declared `myBoard` inside the constructor, that's it. Is there smth that I dont understand??

Comment: @John if you just do this it will never work, because in your constructor you only create an empty list of lists. I had not seen that at first

Answer (score 1):

When you do `board.set(-1, 0, "A");`, you are trying to access the element at index -1 of your `ArrayList`. `row` is -1 in `set()` and you essentially call `myBoard.get(-1)` in your `if` statement.

You need to remember that `ArrayList` is 0-based with regard to indexing. To fix this, subtract the minimum index from your -1 to get the correct index. This goes for the column index as well. For example, given

```
Board board = new Board(-2,3,-4,3,"xxx");
```

You need to do

```
int row = (-1) - (-2);     //row you want - lowest row (row at index 0 in the ArrayList)
int col = (0) - (-4);      //col you want - lowest col (col at index 0 in the ArrayList)
board.set(row, col, "A");
```

Comment: This indexing is way too confusing and error-prone. If he needs negative indices, then the `Board` class needs to know how to rewrite negative indices to positive ones, but it should not be up to the user to do it

Comment: @Dici I agree. I was simply trying to show where his mistake was, and push him in the right direction to start working out a solution, not provide the best and most perfect solution.

Comment: Mmm ok, that's a choice. +1 then.

Answer (score 1):

Negative indices are invalid for all ordered data-structures in Java. Your `Board` class should rewrite the indices to positive ones to hide this funky logic from the caller :

```
public void set(int virtualRow, int virtualCol, T x) {
    int row = translateIndex(minRow, virtualRow, maxRow);
    int col = translateIndex(minCol, virtualCol, maxCol);

    // this.expandToInclude(row, col);
    if (myBoard.get(row).get(col).equals(this.element)) {
        myBoard.get(row).set(col, x);
        RowColStack<T> temp = new RowColStack<T>(row, col, x);
        undoStack.add(temp);
    }
}

private int translateIndex(int min, int index, int max) {
    if (index< min || row > max) throw new ArrayOutOfBoundException();
    return index - min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of comments:

1. Once you know the size of board (which doesn't seem to be changing during the execution of the program) it may be much simpler to use a 2D array instead of `ArrayList`.
2. You are not creating elements in the array list in the initialization. So in effect you have a 0x0 array, and will be receiving `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for any get calls.
3. You can of course receive negative indices, but convert them to proper indices into the array/arraylist before accessing elements as mentioned in the other answers.

You can initialise your array list using some logic similar to below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
   rowList = new ArrayList();
   myboard.add(rowList); 
   for(int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
      rowList.add(null);
   }
}
```

Consider this as pseudo code and build on it.

Comment: that is my main concern. How should I create create elements in the arraylist in the initialization? @KDM

Comment: If have `T element` can I do `rowList.add(j, this.element)` inside the for-loop?, @KDM

Comment: @John you should be able to.